# How to extends KAA to allow send event from server to EPs?

Tags: kaa

How to extends KAA to allow send events from server to EPs ?  Something like send notifications via REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Events are not intended for it, they responsible for messaging only across connected devices. Use notifications for this purpose, you can send them via [REST API](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API#AdminRESTAPI-Sendnotification) or [Administration UI](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Administration+UI+guide#AdministrationUIguide-Sendingnotifications). See [key features of Kaa](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Kaa+IoT+Platform+Home) for more information.

Comment: Yes, i understand, but it could be very useful for testing purpose. I just wonder if there is anyway to implement this.

Comment: You can always embed an SDK to a standalone application and host in on the same server where kaa-node is present. This application may receive REST API calls and forward them to particular endpoints via Kaa events feature. However, this is useful for test purposes. I would not recommend this solution in production because it is hard to scale and has potential security issues.